# unresolved references in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

Here in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqUTf.png) you can see that I can't able to `import` the image ID through `Glide`, I'm a beginner to android development. I tried this and I done exactly same what he had done but in my case `import` option is not there.

Comment: please do not post images here, rather explain your question properly. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

add Dependence
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'

Then Sync gradle and try again